# BreezeJS - Chaining Queries

Tags: javascript, breeze, q

Say we have a Customer Object, that has a "Foo" collection.  I'd like my "getCustomer" function to add all Foos it does not have already, and then return itself, as a promise...

So I'd like a promise to: Get a Customer, then add all missing Foos to this Customer, so that when the promise is resolved, the customer has all missing foos.

Example:

```
// dataservice.js

// returns Q.Promise<breeze.QueryResult>
function getCustomer(custId) {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery().from("Customers").where("CustomerId", "==", custId);
    return this.em.executeQuery(query);
}

// returns Q.Promise<breeze.QueryResult>
function getFoosNotOnCustomer(customer) {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery().from("Foo").where("CustomerId", "!=", customer.Id());
    return this.em.executeQuery(query);
}
```

I am struggling with how to "chain" these together properly, what do do if no customer is found, etc. How can I modify "getCustomer" to do this?  I am basically trying to user breeze synchronously. Here is my attempt, but it turns into ugly nested code in a hurry.

```
   // want to return Q.Promise<Customer> that has Foos loaded
   // I think this is actually returning something like Q.Promise<Q.Promise<Customer>>
    function getCustomer(custId) {
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery().from("Customers")
                .where("CustomerId", "==", custId);

        return this.em.executeQuery(query) // return here?
               .then(function(data) {
                    // what about conditionals?
                    if(data.results.length == 1) {
                        getFoosNotOnCustomer(data.results[0]).
                        then(function (foosArray) {
                             $.each(foosArray, function(i,el) {
                                 // push foos onto customer instance
                             }
                             return custWithFoos; // return here?
                        }
                       // return something? 
                    }
                 }
    }
```

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
 function getCustomer(custId) {

     var query = breeze.EntityQuery().from("Customers").where("CustomerId", "==", custId);

     return manager.executeQuery(query) // return here?
         .then(addFoos)
         .then(doSomethingElse);
}
 function addFoos(data) {
     var myDefer = Q.Defer();

     if (data && data.result.length == 1) {
         var customer = data.results[0];
         var query = // get FOOS Customer doesn't have;
         manager.executeQuery(query).then(function (fooData) {
             $.each(fooData.results function (i, el) {
                 customer.Foos.push(el);
             });
             myDefer.reslove(customer);
         });
     } else {
         myDefer.resolve(undefined);
     }

     return myDefer.promise;
 }

 function doSomethingElse(customer) {
     var myDefer = Q.Defer();
     customer.SomePropert("test");
     return myDefer.resovlve(customer);
 }

 // ----- MVVM
 var custPromise = getCustomer(1).then(function (customer) {
     // do something
 });
```

Comment: I do not understand what you're trying to do. I can help you chain the queries ... so that the second query depends on the first ... if that is what you want. But your example confuses me, given that, as written, you know the CustomerId for both queries when you start. You could issue these in parallel and then resume when both complete. But I sense I'm missing something. Also I don't know what "all missing Foos" means either. Your second query appears to request all Foos in the db that do not belong to the target customer. Is that really what you mean?

Comment: Ward, yes. I want to load the Customer entity.  Then I want to find all Foos that the customer instance does not have and push them into the customer instance collection.  What to return where is where I get confused and the code becomes unreadable.  I will update the question with a better example.

Comment: What if you ask for Customer with ID=1 and there are Foos belonging to a Customer with ID=2. This logic is going to take all of the Foos for Customer #2 and move them to Customer #1. Is that really what you intend? Note that your first query does not retrieve the Foos that already belong to Customer #1. So at the end of the operations you are requesting, the in-cache, Customer1.Foos will return no Foos that used to belong to Customer #1 and all Foos used to belong to any other Customer. I don't get it.

Comment: No problem - I tried to make my example too abstract. I think I figured it out - Q.defer was what I needed.  Thanks for the help; I will close this question.

Comment: Q.defer? I don't know that I would need that for anything that sounds like your case. See my answer

Comment: Ward, it was a many-to-many relationship, so Customer doesn't "own" Foos, rather they are attributes that can be added to any customer, and I wanted to add any they didn't have when the customer was loaded.  I was really just having a hard time grasping chaining functions together by returning promises - i think mostly from fighting typing in typescript, and I ended up using a deferred under the "what about condtionals?" comment.  I didn't see your answer. Anyways, I didn't get my question across very well.

Comment: Ward FYI - I added my "solution" at the bottom. It seems I needed Q.defer because of my conditional, how else would I have a return value.  Maybe there's a better way without deferreds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will take your example on face value despite my inability to understand the semantics ... in particular my inability to understand why getting all Foos not belonging to the customer is going to be helpful.

I'll just focus on "chaining" and I'll assume you want the caller to take possession of the selected customer when you're done.

### Sequential chaining

In this example, we wait for the customer before getting the Foos

```
function getCustomer(custId) {

    var cust;
    var em = this.em;
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery().from("Customers")
                .where("CustomerId", "==", custId);

    // On success calls `gotCustomer` which itself returns a promise
    return em.executeQuery(query)
        .then(gotCustomer)
        .fail(handleFail); // you should handleFail 

    // Called after retrieving the customer.
    // returns a new promise that the original caller will wait for.
    // Defined as a nested success function 
    // so it can have access to the captured `cust` variable 
    function gotCustomer(data) {
       cust = data.results[0];

       if (!cust) {
          return null; // no customer with that id; bail out now
       }
       // got a customer so look for non-customer foos
       // returning another promise so caller will wait
       return breeze.EntityQuery().from("Foos")
              .where("CustomerId", "!=", custId)
              .using(em).execute()
              .then(gotFoos);
    }

    // Now you have both the customer and the other Foos;
    // bring them together and return the customer.
    function gotFoos(data) {
        var foos = data.results;
        // assume `notMyFoos` is an unmapped property that 
        // should hold every Foo that doesn't belong to this Customer
        foos.forEach(function(f) { cust.notMyFoos.push(f); }
        return cust; // return the customer to the caller after Foos arrive.
    }
}
```

### Parallel async queries

In your scenario you really don't have to wait for the customer query before getting the foos. You know the selection criterion for both the customer and the foos from the start. *Assuming you think that there is a high probability that the customer query will return a customer*, you might fire off both queries in parallel and then mash up the data when both queries complete. Consider the [`Q.all`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) for this.

```
function getCustomer(custId) {
    var em = this.em;

    var custPromise = breeze.EntityQuery().from("Customers")
                      .where("CustomerId", "==", custId)
                      .using(em).execute();

    var fooPromise = breeze.EntityQuery().from("Foos")
                      .where("CustomerId", "!=", custId)
                      .using(em).execute();

    Q.all([custPromise, fooPromise])
      .then(success)
      .fail(handleFail); // you should handleFail

    // Now you have both the customer and the "other" Foos;
    // bring them together and return the customer.
    // `data` is an array of the results from each promise in the order requested.
    function success(data) {
        var cust = data[0].results[0];
        if (!cust) return null;

        var foos = data[1].results;

        // assume `notMyFoos` is an unmapped property that 
        // should hold every Foo that doesn't belong to this Customer
        foos.forEach(function(f) { cust.notMyFoos.push(f); }
        return cust; // return the customer to the caller after Foos arrive.
    }
}
```

Notice that I don't have to do so much null checking in the success paths. I'm guaranteed to have `data.results` when the success callback is called.  I do have to account for the possibility that there is no `Customer` with `custId`.

Comment: I think I struggled with the sequential solution because I tried to do it it without the cust variable that you have available to the 2 functions.  But who cares, your parallel solution is way better!

Comment: It *may* be better. It has the defect that it gets Foos even when there is no customer with the given custId. That's why I added the note about *high probability that the customer query will return a customer*. Your UI could make that probability very high (e.g., selection from a list) in which case the parallelism could be good for your app. However, when it comes to perf, I don't assume anything. So many theoretical args turn out to be wrong. Test and verify. Have fun!